# What is the German / European equivalent of FAA Order 7110.65?

Tags: air-traffic-control, easa-regulations, phraseology, eu, germany

FAA Order 7110.65 prescribes air traffic control procedures and phraseology for use by personnel providing ATC services in the USA.

Which documents regulate these aspects in Germany, or, more generally, in Europe?

Please provide also the valid versions of these documents as of the 1st of April 2020.

Answer (score 3):

The „handbook“ for ATCOs in **Germany** (!) is the **MO-ATS** (Manual of Operations for Air Traffic Services) which is an internal DFS (Deutsche Flugsicherung - the German ANSP) document and therefore not available to public.

However it is based on the **German AIP** and **ICAO DOC 4444** which are both available to public. For the international legislation check Milo Morkus’ answer.

In the German AIP phraseology examples are found in **AIP ED GEN 3.4 Communication Services**

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like a "handbook" for ATC procedures and phraseology for use by personnel providing ATC services in EU states.
There is a civil aviation authority (CAA) in each country of the EU. EASA (EU AVIATION SAFETY AGENCY) provides its own regulations for flying in EU airspace.
The EU standards are "regulated or guided" by ICAO documents and annexes.
ICAO SARPS (Standards and Recommended Practices) for each area of ICAO responsibility are published in **19 Annexes**. Each Annex deals with a particular subject area and is subject to regular amendments. The details of many of them are contained in publications in the numbered ICAO Document Series.
 The **ICAO Documents** cover a range of matters from regulations to guidance. Some are available to the public without charge while others are only obtainable at a fee.

Description of ICAO Annexes [ICAO link](https://www.icao.int/safety/airnavigation/NationalityMarks/annexes_booklet_en.pdf)

Description of ICAO Annexes [ICAO DOC link](https://www.icao.int/publications/Pages/doc-series.aspx)

**Documents and Annex "examples" for ATC services and personnel:**

[Annex 2 – Rules of the Air](https://www.icao.int/Meetings/anconf12/Document%20Archive/an02_cons%5B1%5D.pdf)

Annex 3 – Meteorological Service for International Air Navigation

Annex 10/II – Aeronautical Telecommunication, Volume II (Communication Procedures)

Annex 11 – Air Traffic Services

Annex 14 - Aerodromes

Doc 4444 – PANS-ATM - Air Traffic Management – Procedures for Air Navigation Services

Doc 7030/4 – Regional Supplementary Procedures.

[ICAO Doc 4444](https://ops.group/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ICAO-Doc4444-Pans-Atm-16thEdition-2016-OPSGROUP.pdf) (air traffic management)]

**EASA (EU AVIATION SAFETY AGENCY) **
EASA Supports its Member States in implementing those ICAO standards, for example through the compliance checklists (CC) ([details on EASA webpage](https://www.easa.europa.eu/easa-and-you/international-cooperation/cooperation-with-ICAO)).

> The CCs show the status of implementation of ICAO Standards and  Recommended Practices (SARPs) in a particular State, as well as any differences that may exist between the national/European regulations and the ICAO SARPS

**EASA started with [eRules project](https://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/general-publications/easy-access-rules-air-traffic-managementair-navigation#group-easa-related-content).**.

> EASA eRules will be a comprehensive, single system for the drafting, sharing and storing of rules. It will be the single source for all aviation safety rules applicable to European airspace users. It will offer easy (online) access to all rules and regulations as well as new and innovative applications such as rulemaking process automation, stakeholder consultation, cross-referencing, and comparison with ICAO and third countries’ standards.